# all pairs correlation on a sparse matrix

Tags: r, data.table

I have written some code to compute correlations between all pairs of ids in a dataset.  The input and output formats are shown below:

```
Input:  obsid | varid | value
Output: obsid1 | obsid2 | correl
```

I realize that correlation and all-pairs function(s) are available and discussed on SO before.  This may be different because I am using a key/value or deep format for input and output.  Also, the instances that I need to solve have ~200,000 observations and ~500 variables with density 20%.  Effectively I need to compute 4 x 10^10 correlations!  So, I am hoping to make this very efficient.

Here's the code to create an instance:

```
require(data.table)

CreateInstance <- function(nobs,nvar,density) {
    dtbl <- data.table(
        do.call("rbind", 
            lapply(1:nobs, function(n) { 
                v <- which(runif(nvar)<density)
                if(length(v)>0) {cbind(n,v)}
            })
        )
    )
    setnames(dtbl, c("obsid","varid"))
    dtbl$value <- as.numeric(sample(1:50, nrow(dtbl), replace=TRUE))
    return(dtbl)
}
```

The code is run as follows:

```
set.seed(100)
nobs <- 10
nvar <- 4
dens <- .5
inst <- CreateInstance(nobs,nvar,dens)
```

The code to compute all correlations for 1 observation and choose top N

```
GetCorrelationsForObs <- function(n) {
    dtbl <- inst[inst[obsid==n,2:3,with=FALSE]][, list(sumxy=sum(value*i.value)), by=obsid]
    if(nrow(dtbl)==0) {return(data.table(obsid1=integer(0),obsid2=integer(0),correl=numeric(0)))}
    dtbl <- inst.summ[dtbl][obsid!=n]
    infoy <- inst.summ[obsid==n,c(sumx,sdx)]
    dtbl <- dtbl[, list(obsid2=obsid, 
        correl=(nvar*sumxy-infoy[1]*sumx)/(infoy[2]*sdx))][!is.na(correl),][order(-rank(correl))]
    return(if(nrow(dtbl)>nbors) cbind(obsid1=n,dtbl[1:nbors]) else cbind(obsid1=n,dtbl))
}
```

This code is run using

```
inst.summ <- inst[, list(sumx=sum(value), sdx=sqrt(nvar*sum(value^2)-sum(value)^2)), by="obsid"]
nbors <- 2
setkey(inst,varid)
setkey(inst.summ,obsid)
correl.dt <- data.table(do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nobs, GetCorrelationsForObs) ))
```

For a larger instance `nobs <- 200000`, `nvar <- 500`, `dens <- .2`, `nbors <- 100`, it takes 38seconds for 50calls to `GetCorrelationsForObs`.

QUESTION: I realize that the problem is [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) and I can easily do the needful to run it in parallel.  I am looking for inputs on how to make `GetCorrelationsForObs` to run faster. This is the first time I am using data.table and would like understand if it can be made to run faster (different keys? other options?).  Thanks.

Comment: Speed question => provide `Rprof()` output.   That might point to `do.call` or `rbind` and then search for "do.call rbind speed".   Use a plain `for` loop to time `nobs` calls to `GetCorrelationsForObs` to see if it's really that or the `do.call rbind` around it.  Maybe.